# add projects into single git repo from different folders

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree, smartgit

I have a organization with a repo named samples. These contain samples projects from different environments, thus have different folders.

```
organization name: alpha
repo: samples
       + env1
       + env2
       + env3
```

These projects are present in 3 different workspace locally. What is the best way to push these into git repo.

I currently have 1 project pushed, while pushing another project in sourcetree I am trying to

1. pushTo: www.github.com/alpha/samples/env2/

I get folder not found error. Its true that this is folder is not present, and it git does not allow me to add empty folder, how should I go about this?

Comment: You can't push to a subdirectory in Git. You can only push to a repository. It's a little hard to understand what you're looking for; perhaps [submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) would help?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use folders or branches.

Which strategy is the best mainly depends on your needs. But, as you already have those as folders, I guess you would like to maintain that approach.

Anyhow, let's see both.

**FOLDERS**

Being in `sample` folder, create as many directories as environment you have.
So you'll have those directories:

- env1
- env2
- env3

each with its file.

Now run

```
for env in env1 env2 env3
git add $env 
git commit -m "Adding ${env}"
done
```

that to have each environment on a single commit. Of course you can add and commit all together: it's up to you.

Then push to github

> git push origin master

supposing you're working on master and mapped GitHub as origin (that's the default behavior as well)

**BRANCHES**
For each environment switch to a new branch:

```
git checkout -b branch_name
```

add the files/directories from any environment you want to track:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Adding environment X"
git push origin branch_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a branch for each subdirectory.

```
git checkout -b <branch name> //env1, env2, and env3, I suppose
```

Modify the .gitignore as necessary to ignore the other
directories when you push to the branch.

Then when you want to switch to another project, commit
your changes:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "<your message>"
git push origin <branch name> //Optional
git checkout <other branch name>
```

and switch to the other branch with the `git checkout` command.